# How do you uncurry/reverse curry in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I have a function I have to wrap another function if it exists or replace it if it doesn't. This means the number of arguments changes depending on the circumstance.

Here's what I mean -

List of columns:

```
const myColumns = [
    {name: 'My Field', formatter: function(row, cell, value, colDef, data){
        ... do stuff to value...
        return value;
    },
    {name: 'My Other Field'}
]
```

Some have formatters and some don't. Here's my partial solution for 'wrapping' the function:

```
return myColumns.map(columns => {
    function wrapFormatting(value){
        return `<span class="foobar">${value}</value>`
    }
    if( column.formatters ) {
        column.formatters = _.flow(column.formatter, wrapFormatting);
    } else {
        column.formatter = (row, cell, value) => value => wrapFormatting;
    }
})
```

My naive expectation is that in the `else` block formatter we 'reverse curry'/uncurry the three arguments and it would end up looking like this:

```
column.formatter = function(row, cell, value){
    wrapFormatting(value);
}
```

But eslint is telling me that value is a) already declared in the upper scope and b) defined but never used. If I change one of them (so I have `(row, cell, value) => val => wrapFormatting` I have them both as 'defined but never used'.

I feel like I've missed a trick, because I can't have `(row, cell, value) => value => wrapFormatting(value)` as that will immediately invoke the function, and it won't be called when column.formatter is called.

Comment: "*`(row, cell, value) => value => wrapFormatting(value)` will immediately invoke the function*" - why do you think so?

Comment: @Bergi because of this bit *`wrapFormatting(value)`*

Comment: Well but your `function(row, cell, value){ …` contains the exact same bit. Why wouldn't it immediately invoke it there?

Comment: @Bergi I was having a brain fart and thought `function  fooBar(...` and `function(...` did somehting different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

```
column.formatter = (row, cell, value) => wrapFormatting(value);
```

Not sure why you thought you'd have `value` as parameter twice and never call `wrapFormatting` but return it.

Comment: Me neither. Won't that immediately call the wrapFormatting?

Comment: @Pureferret no, it defines a function. If you're uncomfortable with arrow functions, you might as well use the equivalent `function` syntax that you have presented in your question